how to migrate features from azure databricks workspace to gcp?
I’m in the process of migrating feature tables from Azure Databricks to GCP Databricks and am having trouble listing all feature tables from Azure Databricks.
I’ve tried using the FeatureStoreClient API, but it doesn’t have a function to list all feature tables, and I couldn’t find a REST API endpoint for this purpose either.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to list all feature tables in Azure Databricks? Any guidance or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
I’ve tried using the FeatureStoreClient API, but it doesn’t have a function to list all feature tables, and I couldn’t find a REST API endpoint for this purpose either.

can you try alternating approached of Using Azure Databricks' Delta Table Listing or use Databricks REST API?

You can use this rest api to list the tables https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/tables/list
